# How to store the AES Key in database using JavaKeyStore, currently i am storing the key in a folder with .JCEKS extension,

Tags: java, security, encryption

How to Store the AES Key in Database using JavaKeyStore, please check the complete code and its straight forward. Currently i am storing the Key in .JCEKS extension in a given location, need to store the Key in database and read it back for encryption. Please help me out.

Note: This code is working any one who wants to encrypt and decrypt and store the date in the database use my code. Key generated gets save in file format and is retrieved back for reuse, encrypt or decrypt.

```
package user.dao;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import de.blowfish.core.Blowfish;

import user.util.UserConstants;

import user.bean.UserLoginBean;
import user.util.DButil;



public class UserDao {

public int insertUserDetails(Object bean)
{

    user.bean.UserLoginBean beanobj=(UserLoginBean)bean;
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    PreparedStatement ps1=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int result=0;
    try{

    conn=DButil.getConnection();
    StringBuffer sbinsert=new StringBuffer();
    sbinsert.append("insert into ");
    sbinsert.append(UserConstants.USER_DETAILS_TABLE_NAME);
    sbinsert.append(" values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    //KeyStore Table

    conn=DButil.getConnection();
    StringBuffer sbinsert1 =new StringBuffer();
    sbinsert1.append("insert into ");
    sbinsert1.append(UserConstants.USER_DETAILS_TABLE_NAME1);
    sbinsert1.append(" values(?,?)");

    //

    Security.addProvider(new blowfishProvider());


    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "blowfish");
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "blowfish");
    SecretKey secKey = keyGen.generateKey();



    // Storing the secret Key
                final String keyStoreFile = "C:\\mykey.jceks";
                 //String keyStoreFile = new String(sbinsert1);
                //final String keyStoreDB = beanobj.getKeylock();
                 KeyStore keyStore = createKeyStore(keyStoreFile, "java0123");
                 System.out.println("Stored Key: " + (secKey));
                 System.out.println("secured key: " + (keyStore));


    // store the secret key
                 KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry keyStoreEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secKey);
                 PasswordProtection keyPassword = new PasswordProtection("www-secret".toCharArray());
                 keyStore.setEntry("mySecretKey", keyStoreEntry, keyPassword);
                 keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile), "java0123".toCharArray());
                 //keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStoreDB), "java0123".toCharArray());


    //Encryption of string
    String clearText = beanobj.getPassword() ;
    byte[] clearTextBytes = clearText.getBytes("UTF8");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
    byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearTextBytes);
    String cipherText = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8");

    //Decryption of String
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey );
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
    String decryptedText = new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF8");

    System.out.println("Before encryption: " + clearText);
    System.out.println("After encryption: " + cipherText);
    System.out.println("After decryption: " + decryptedText);

    //


    ps=conn.prepareStatement(sbinsert.toString());
    ps.setString(1,beanobj.getFirstname());
    ps.setString(2, beanobj.getLastname());
    ps.setString(3, beanobj.getUsername());
    ps.setString(4, cipherText);
    ps.setString(5, beanobj.getEmail());
    ps.setString(6, beanobj.getMobileno());

    ps1=conn.prepareStatement(sbinsert1.toString());
    beanobj.setKeylock("mykey"); // Dummy key for checking if logic works
    ps1.setString(1,beanobj.getUsername());
    ps1.setString(2,beanobj.getKeylock());

    result=ps.executeUpdate();
    result=ps1.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();


    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        DButil.closeAllDBResources(conn, ps, null);
    }
    return result;


    }
public boolean isRegisteredUser(String un,String pw)
{
    boolean result=false;
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try
    {
        conn=DButil.getConnection();
        StringBuffer sbselect=new StringBuffer();
        sbselect.append("select * from ");
        sbselect.append(UserConstants.USER_DETAILS_TABLE_NAME);
        sbselect.append(" where BINARY Username=? and Password=?");
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sbselect.toString());


        // Retreving the key 

        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "FlexiCore");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        System.out.println(keyStore);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\mykey.jceks";);

        keyStore.load(fis, "java0123".toCharArray());              
        Key secKey = keyStore.getKey("mySecret","www-secret".toCharArray());


        //Encrypting the User Passowrd and comparing with the DB enPassword one way process

        String clearText = pw ;
        byte[] clearTextBytes = clearText.getBytes("UTF8");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher1.doFinal(clearTextBytes);
        String cipherText1 = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8");




        ps.setString(1, un);
        ps.setString(2, cipherText1);
        //System.out.println(ps.toString());
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            result=true;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        DButil.closeAllDBResources(conn, ps, rs);
    }


    return result;
}
public int executeUpdate(String query)
{
    int result=0;
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try
    {
        conn=DButil.getConnection();
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        result=ps.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally{
        DButil.closeAllDBResources(conn, ps, null);
    }
    return result;
}

private static java.security.KeyStore createKeyStore(String keyStoreFile,
        String pw) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     File file = new File("mykey.jceks");
     /**
      * Note that if you are storing a SecretKey or using any part of the SunJCE provider
      *  (Java Cryptography Extension),
      *  you will need to set your KeyStore type to JCEKS.
      */
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        if (file.exists()) {
            // .keystore file already exists => load it
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), www.toCharArray());
        } else {
            // .keystore file not created yet => create it
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("mykey1.jceks"), www.toCharArray());
        }

        return keyStore;
       }

       }
```

Comment: did not get answer for any of my questions

Comment: You have gotten answers that you didn't reply to, and you've answered yourself as well. You can also accept answers by yourself. Personally I don't think the quality of the questions is very high, you often are not bothered by spelling mistakes and such. Some of the questions are barely readable for me and the intention is not always that clear. Same goes for your code - e.g. the exception handling in above code is only confusing the reader, maybe you should try [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Just posting this to help you; I'm afraid you won't get too many answers like this

Answer (score 0):

Change `keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile), "java0123".toCharArray());` and replace the `FileOutputStream` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` to retrieve the resulting blob. Then either store the (variable sized) blob in the byte array directly into your DB.

You may use `CipherOutputStream` connected to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to additionally encrypt the `KeyStore` instance. If you do this then don't forget to close the `CipherOutputStream` or your data may become corrupted.

If you require characters for some reason or other, first base64 encode the blob and store the result.

Comment: Hi KeyStoreFile is a bit tricky, keyStore.store stores the key into a filepath which will be created by javakeystore as i have mentioned already, in KeyStoreFile i should be giving something like this bean.setkeylock(); but logic does'nt go well with JavaKeyStore. I am confused at this part of code and i am stuck, if you could clarify be with code from your side would be help full, i have another keystore concept for storing the encrypted key in database, but looking for a final try with javakeystore

Comment: Changed answer, could you see if this helped clearing up the confusion?